# Sum monthly sales totals and provide output with month name and total for last 3 months

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get monthly sales totals from a MYSQL database and have them summed by month with month name for last X months. The two columns I am targeting are: total_customer_charged and local_time. I almost have my query working correctly, the problem I have is that the order the results come out sometimes changes with each query. Can anyone please give me some hints to get my query correct?

[image]

My existing query is:

```
select date_format(local_time,'%M'),sum(total_customer_charged) FROM ORDERS WHERE local_time BETWEEN curdate() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH AND curdate() group by month(local_time) order by year(local_time),month(local_time)
```

Comment: Post you data sample as text instead of an image!

Answer (score 2):

You should put year into the group-by statement like this:

```sql
select
    date_format(local_time, '%Y') AS agg_year,
    date_format(local_time, '%m') AS agg_month,
    sum(total_customer_charged) AS monthly_total_customer_charged
FROM
    ORDERS
WHERE
    local_time BETWEEN curdate() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH AND curdate()
group by
    date_format(local_time, '%Y'),
    date_format(local_time, '%m')
order by
    agg_year,
    agg_month
```

Comment: Thanks @quasi-human, the only problem I get with this is the order in which the results come out, I would expect chronological order by month but the result I get running this is August 2021 - 10.48
December 2021 - 22.70
November 2021 - 10.48
January 2022 - 527.51

Comment: One solution I came up with was to put the results into an array in PHP and use uksort to put into the correct order. There must be a way to have them come out of the DB in correct order though?

Comment: I have no idea what you want to make. Can you clarify the expected result?

Comment: I am using the data month and month_total to plot a graph (x,y). So the order that the results come out of the query is important. In this case it would be good to have the results come out as, Aug, Nov, Dec, Jan. When I run the query the results come out as Aug, Dec, Nov, Jan.

Comment: I now understand you want to ignore year information, while I still don't understand why your desirable order is Aug, Nov, Dec, Jan in this case, not Jan, Aug, Nov, Dec.
Can you tell me the very first month in your desirable monthly order? A fiscal year depends on countries.

Comment: For example if my graph is going to show sales data for last 6 months. On my graph i would like to see along the X axis, the month starting at Aug 2021 ending at current month, Jan 2022.

Comment: Okay, I understand it now. I found that I used a wrong specifier for months. My apology. I edited my original answer, so can you try that code again?

Comment: About the specifier, please read this document: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(local_time), SUM(total_customer_charged) 
FROM ORDERS 
GROUP BY YEAR(local_time), MONTH(local_time)
```